# 9903-MYSQL data path error I am getting an unexpected packet format error. What could be the cause of the problem?

Tags: phpmyadmin

When I run the integration to send the price vw stock update from the ERP system to my website, I get 9903-MYSQL data path error, unexpected package format error. What could be the cause of the problem?

When I check the codes, there is no problem.